# convert `java.sql.blob` into `javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource`

Tags: java, xml

What is an efficient way to convert a `java.sql.blob` into `javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource`?

Here is what I have so far, but it seems overly complicated and perhaps resource intensive:

```
StreamSource inputStream = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(myBlob.getBytes(1,(int)myBlob.length())));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not the following, which is simpler?

```
new StreamSource(myBlob.getBinaryStream())
```

Performance, of course, depends on the implementation, but I see no reason why either your suggested approach or this one should be inefficient. Neither actually necessitates copying the data, at least in principle.